# Moving text annotations in Xournal

Tags: pdf-reader, annotations

Is it possible to move text annotations in Xournal? If so how?

Seems to be a trivial task, but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to move text annotations in Xournal. Follow the following steps:

1. Click in the toolbar on the "Select Region" or "Select Rectangle" button.
   [image]
2. Click on the annotation in the document.
3. Now you can drag the annotation to a different location.

Comment: Right. In my version (0.4.5) it is hidden under "Tools -> Select Rectangle". There's no button.

Comment: I'm using Xournal 0.4.7.

Comment: I'm also (still) using version 0.4.5.  FYI, the keyboard shortcut used to evoke the "Select Rectangle" mode is "Shift-Control-r".

Answer (score 8):

In xournal++ 1.1.0 it's slightly changed, to "Select Object".

Click the dropdown circled below (which may either have the mouse-arrow pictured, or it may have a square), and choose "Select Object".

Or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

[image: menu for moving text in xournal++]

Comment: Note that arrow is in a dropdown. By default it looks like a square (Select Rectangle) for me.

Comment: @Timmmm changed answer accordingly, thx

Answer (score 7):

**I succeed to move text like this:**

After writing text in any location in the document:

- I went to the upper toolbar and choose the **"Select rectangle"** button (instead of the **"Text"** button). Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>.
- Now, in this state, I dragged the text to any other location in the page.

After that, you can go back again to "Text" mode and edit the text as before (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd>).

- I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and currently it installs Xournal 0.4.5 by default.

Comment: For me these shortcuts are Ctrl-Shift-R and Ctrl-Shift-T.